# Python 3 not aware of Windows filename encodings?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, encoding, path, filenames

The following code works well in Win7 until it crashes in the last print(f). It does it when it finds some "exotic" characters in the filenames, as the french "oe" as in œuvre and the C in Karel Čapek. The program crashes with an Encoding error, saying the character x in the filename is'nt a valid utf-8 char.
Should'nt Python3 be aware of the utf-16 encoding of the Windows7 paths?
How should I modify my code?

```
import os

rootDir = '.'
extensions = ['mobi','lit','prc','azw','rtf','odt','lrf','fb2','azw3' ]
files=[]
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    files.extend((os.path.join(dirName,fn) for fn in fileList if any([fn.endswith(ext) for ext in extensions])))

for f in files:
    print(f)
```

Comment: Python 3's raw `FileIO` class forces binary mode, which precludes using a UTF-16 text mode for the Windows console. Thus the default setup is limited to using an OEM/ANSI codepage. To avoid raising an exception, you'd have to use a less-strict 'replace' or 'backslashreplace' mode for `sys.stdout`. Switching to codepage 65001 (UTF-8) seems like it should be the answer, but the console host (conhost.exe) has problems with multibyte encodings. That leaves the UTF-16 wide-character API, such as via the [win-unicode-console](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console) module.

Comment: I see it's not thet easy. I don't mind some qiestion marks in the place of characters, but i would like my program not to crash on a simple print...

Comment: If you don't mind printing question marks, then use `sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.detach(), sys.stdout.encoding, 'replace')`. Otherwise use `win_unicode_console`.

Comment: The win-unicode-console module solved the problem, without having to modify my code, just one line at the top to enable it Not only my print(files) does'nt crash, even the exotic characters are displayed. Thankes erkysun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eryksun answered my question in a comment. I copy his answer here so the thread does'nt stand as unanswered, The [win-unicode-console](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/win_unicode_console) module solved the problem:

> Python 3's raw FileIO class forces binary mode, which precludes using
>   a UTF-16 text mode for the Windows console. Thus the default setup is
>   limited to using an OEM/ANSI codepage. To avoid raising an exception,
>   you'd have to use a less-strict 'replace' or 'backslashreplace' mode
>   for sys.stdout. Switching to codepage 65001 (UTF-8) seems like it
>   should be the answer, but the console host (conhost.exe) has problems
>   with multibyte encodings. That leaves the UTF-16 wide-character API,
>   such as via the win-unicode-console module.